# Inserting CSS animations using DOM

Tags: jquery, css, dom, jquery-plugins, css-animations

I want to dynamically change CSS3 animations using using  jQueries .css() I am using the Animate.css library to provide the base animation and Waypoints.js to activate the animations. However the function doesn't execute and it doesn't trigger an error. What am I doing wrong?

```
jQuery("#animateme").waypoint(function(direction){
                        if(direction === "down"){

                            jQuery('#animateme').removeClass("animated flash");
                            jQuery('#animateme').addClass("animated pulse").css({animation: function(){


                                        var jwduration = "2";
                                        var jwtime = "linear";
                                        var jwdelay = "2";
                                        var jwiteration = "2";

                                return (jwduration + "s " + jwtime " " + jwdelay + "s " + jwiteration + " "  );
                            }});

                        }
                     if(direction === "up"){

                            jQuery('#animateme').removeClass("animated pulse");
                            jQuery('#animateme').addClass("animated flash");
                        }

});
```

Comment: One thing that stands out is the double bracket at the end of your animation function. }});

Comment: That is a jQuery CSS syntax option so you can do multiple pairs .css({background-color: #444},{color: #000});